# How to create random cell number for testing purpose

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to create a random cellnumber 07939393914 for automation testing purpose.

Last 079393(5 digits) digits should change randamly.. each time test runs..

Can any one suggest JAVA code for this ? or else Selenium Java code ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what have u tried?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having trouble? (And why have you tagged your question `javascript` if you're asking for Java?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-number-in-a-range-with-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a number or a String?  I ask as it has a leading zero.
Take you initial number as 7939300000
then add to it `Math.round(Math.Random()*10000)`

If you want it as a `String`, take your string as "079393" and use `Integer.toString` on the result above, then concatentate them

Comment: It's a phone number. So basically, a string. The leading `0` is important.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry misread that.  String it is

Comment: import java.util.Random;
public class random{
public static void main(String args[]){
System.out.println("random number generation");
Random obj= new Random(); //create object for random class
 
int rgen1= obj.nextInt(1000);//get random number with in the range of 0-1000

String cellnum = ("079393" + rgen1);
System.out.println(cellnum);
 
//if u want double random number use obj.nextDouble()
}
}

Answer (score 2):

Use RandomStringUtils class.

```
String randomNumbers = RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(5);
String phNo = 079393+randomNumbers;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num=Math.ceil(Math.Random()*100000)
```

for random first 5 digit numbers
and add
      `var your_last_5digits;` //as string to your last 5 digits

```
cellNumber='0'+num+your_last_5digits;
```